# using siege, ab, whatever to benchmark 304 not modified responses

Tags: ab

Is it possible by simple tools like `ab` or `siege` to check a server's http 304 not modified response performance?

I have a system that shold provide file changes in realtime, so the user agent has to validate on every occasion, resulting in a lot of 304 responses compared to a low amount of 200 responses actually serving the body.

I would like to stress the system with the usual use case, where most fetches result in 304 responses and only some in 200.